# Split field by comma in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a database field containing long text.

I want it to be split by comma separator and printed on the next line.

For example:

```
Field  : Description

Data   : Hibernate Query Language (HQL) is an object-oriented query language, similar to SQL, but instead of operating on tables and columns, HQL works with persistent objects and their properties.
```

I want it to be printed as:

```
Hibernate Query Language (HQL) is an object-oriented query language, 

similar to SQL,

but instead of operating on tables and columns,

HQL works with persistent objects and their properties.
```

Answer (score 3):

In your query, you can replace commas with ",\n".  The "\n" will force a new line in your Jasper text field.

In MYSQL you can use the REPLACE function.  It looks like this:

```
REPLACE(FIELDNAME, ',', ',\n')
```

Comment: You could use REPLACE(FIELDNAME, ',', '\n') if you do not wish to show the commas in the results.